# How to remove the left padding in textEdit and TextEditLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, textinput, android-textinputlayout

I have used TextEdit to be able to enter an email in a form.

I have declared it as below:

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/gainsboro_03"
                android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                android:hint="@string/email">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_et"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:minWidth="300dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.onEmailTextChanged}"/>


            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The strange things is that I keep getting a left padding and I can't remove it as shown on the image.

[image]

The text and the line are not aligned. I expect the text to be aligned with the line

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` on `TextInputEditText` like bellow

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/email_et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.onEmailTextChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works just fine. Any chances you may know how to change the color of the  hint? For now the hint has a color defined and it works but I would like to make it changes when there is a focus. so basically when the hint is going up and smaller having a different color.